# If $Z(f) \neq \{0\}$ for all $f:V \to V$ then $\dim V < \infty$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Lets $F$ a field and $V$ a vector space over $F$. Consider $f:V \to V$ a linear map, we define $Z(f) = \{p(x) \in F[x], p(f)=0\}$.

Exercise: If $Z(f) \neq \{0\}$ for all $f:V \to V$ then $\dim V  < \infty$.

My Attempt:

Suppose that $\dim V = \infty$ and let  $B= \{v_j\}_{j \in J}$ a basis for $V$. Since every infinity set has a infinity countable subset take $S = \{v_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset B$.

Now take $f:V \to V$ this way:

\begin{align*}
f(v_i)= \begin{cases}
v_{i+1} & \text{if } v_i \in S; \\
0 & \text{if } v_i \notin S
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then we have $f^{k}(v_i) = v_{i+k}$. By assumption $Z(f) \neq \{0\}$, so there is non trivial a polynomial $p(x)= a_0+a_1x+\cdots + a_nx^n$  such that $p(f) = 0$. But $p(f)(v_1) = a_0v_1 + a_1 v_2+ \cdots a_nv_{n+1}=0$, so $B'= \{v_1,v_2,\dots, v_{n+1}\}$ is LD, it is a contradiction because $B'\subset S$ which is LI.

Therefore, $\dim V < \infty$

It is correct??

Comment: The last line is superfluous. You are showing that if $\dim(V)=\infty$, then there exists $f$ such that $Z(f)=\{0\}$. That is the contrapositive of what you want to prove, and there is no need to cast it as a proof by contradiction. Remove the assumption that $Z(f)\neq \{0\}$ and simply show that for a nonzero polynomial $p$, then $p(f)\neq 0$ just as you do. in short: it’s correct, but unnecessarily convoluted as a proof by contradiction instead of a proof by contrapositive.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks for the feedback :)